# How to float clickable image elements in each of the 4 corners of a canvas/div?

Tags: css, html

So I have canvas, in a div. I have 4 elements (images) that I want to float over top of the canvas (google maps controls style) one in each corner. I am trying to figure out the proper html/css combo so that this will work. Ideally, if I resize the canvas on the fly, the elements will continue to float properly spaced from the edges of each of the corners. I would expect that any transforms and translates on the canvas will be entirely isolated from these elements.

```
<div id="content">
     <canvas id="render"></canvas>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
         var canvas = document.getElementById("render");
         canvas.height = 800;
         canvas.width = 900;
     });
</script>
```

The floating elements will likely contain the images using background image css properties, and need to be clickable for jQuery events.

Answer (score 6):

Absolutely position the four elements within `#content`:

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/UTM7x/

```css
#content {
    position: relative;
}
#clickable-1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#clickable-2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#clickable-3 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#clickable-4 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: absolute` on your overlay elements.

[Here is an example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A3F8Z/). It's crude, but it demonstrates well.

HTML:

```
<div id="canvasContainer">
    <canvas></canvas>
    <div class="overlay top left">
        Top left stuff
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#canvasContainer {
    position: relative;
}
#canvasContainer canvas {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background: blue;
}
#canvasContainer div.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #eee;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
​
```